# How would I display two separate tables within the same query/report without combining each entry?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

As of right now, creating a query with all records from both tables I want to display gives me every record for table b for the first record of table a, then every record of table b for the second record of table a, and so on.

```
SELECT *
FROM tblSales, tblRepair;
```

I want to be able to format these tables so that records from each table are displayed within a report, but separately (not joined). Both these tables contain sales data that need to be displayed and calculated together on a daily basis, but my problem right now is getting the data out of these tables and together in a format that doesn't join each record together.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UNION query to combine both tables. I've added a dummy column to distinguish between the two tables:

```
SELECT *,'Sales' AS TheTable FROM tblSales  
UNION ALL SELECT *, 'Repairs' FROM tblRepairs;
```

This will list all the Sales records first, followed by all the Repairs. You can add an ORDER BY clause to change this.

Alternatively, depending on the type of report you are creating, you could base the main report on one table and add a subreport based on the second.